# Integrating eclipse with a different debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, gdb, eclipse-cdt

We have a debugger developed in our company for our own proprietary scripting language. This debugger has the same look and feel like the gdb debugger available in C. It starts  a command prompt and has options for adding breakpoints, printing values, method callflow etc.  Now I have to integrate this debugger with eclipse. Basically eclipse should invoke this debugger which is installed in the same host and the developer should be able to work seamelessly.

I have read some articles on how to create a debugger in eclipse but did-not find any material as to how Eclipse should be "integrated" with a 3rd party debugger. Does eclipse provide any standard APIs, hooks, plugins to go about the same? Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is, of course, open source. Your best course of action is to read the source of the CDT package (the package that integrates GDB etc) and see what extension points it uses. Some of them will be more documented than others.

Answer (score 1):

I did that a while ago for some proprietary language - the API documentation is well written and the extension points very comprehensive.

You might run into trouble if your language has concepts which are not supported by the framework (an painful example was a 'waiting for user' state on top of the classic 'running' and 'suspended'). Other than that, it's straightforward (and time consuming, there are a LOT of views and concepts in the eclipse debugger extensions).

Comment: Hello @ptyx are you saying that you did this using the CDT package ?

Comment: Hello, since you have already used CDT, it will be great if you could give an overview of the major APIs of CDT that you have used for integrating the debugger. Since there are lot of things in CDT, it seems quite exhaustive. So I will be very grateful if you could give me some pointers on how to proceed.

Comment: That was about 2 years ago, so I honestly don't remember much. What I did at the time was look at the CDT, look at the Java debugger, and pretty much copy/pasted the extension points they used and seemed relevant to me. Starting from all that is available in CDT is indeed overwhelming.